# Store modified pixel back into texture memory

Tags: image-processing, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsl, fragment-shader

Hi i am trying to implement a image re-targeting algorithm using openGL ES2.0. This algorithm first uses a Sobel filter and then a image difference to check edges and then motion respectively. It then use these values to create a matrix which will determine which pixels from the image can be removed. I have so far implemented the sobel filter and the image difference using a fragment shader. Once i have the edge map and the motion map i add the two values an normalize them to between 0 and 1. Now i need to again do a sobel filter on this normalized matrix. But i don't know if i can store it back into texture memory to load it as a texture again. Or should i store these values in a matrix the same size as the image? How do i do that using GLSL? (I am a beginner to GLSL. This might be a stupid question :p)

here is the frag shader:

```
precision mediump float;
varying vec2 coordVar;  
uniform sampler2D s_baseMap;
uniform sampler2D s_lightMap;
void main() 
{
    vec4 baseColor; 
    float basemono;
    vec4 lightColor;
    float lightmono;
    float diffmap;
    baseColor = texture2D( s_baseMap, coordVar );
    lightColor = texture2D( s_lightMap, coordVar );
    //######TEMPORAL SALIENCY MAP#########
    basemono = baseColor .r * 0.299 + baseColor .g * 0.587 + baseColor .b * 0.114;
    lightmono = lightColor.r * 0.299 + lightColor.g * 0.587 + lightColor.b * 0.114;
    diffmap = basemono - lightmono;
    //######## SPATIAL SALIENCY MAP #######
    float pixelHSobel;
    float pixelVSobel;
    float pixel;
    mat3 sobelHoriz = mat3(
         0.125,  0.250, 0.125,
         0.000,  0.000, 0.000,
         -0.125,-0.250,-0.125);
         mat3 sobelVert = mat3(
         -0.125, 0, 0.125,
         -0.250, 0, 0.250,
         -0.125, 0, 0.125);
         float stepH = 1.0/800.0;
         float stepV = 1.0/600.0;
         float tmp1;
         float tmp2;
         float tmp3;
         float tmp4;
         float tmp5;
         float tmp6;
         float tmp7;
         float tmp8;
         float tmp9;
      // ####### Horizontal Sobel ######
         tmp1 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, stepV)).r * sobelHoriz[0][0];
         tmp3 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH, stepV)).r * sobelHoriz[2][0];
         tmp4 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, 0.0)).r * sobelHoriz[0][1];
         tmp6 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH,0.0)).r *sobelHoriz[2][1];
         tmp7 = (texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, -stepV)).r *sobelHoriz[0][2]);
         tmp9 = (texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH, -stepV)).r *sobelHoriz[2][2]);
         pixelHSobel = tmp1+tmp3 + tmp4 + tmp6+ tmp7 +  tmp9 + 0.5;
      // ####### Vertical Sobel #######
         tmp1 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, stepV)).r * sobelVert[0][0];
         tmp2 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(0.0, stepV)).r * sobelVert[1][0];
         tmp3 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH, stepV)).r * sobelVert[2][0];
         tmp4 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, 0.0)).r * sobelVert[0][1];
        tmp5 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(0.0, 0.0)).r *sobelVert[1][1];
         tmp6 = texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH,0.0)).r *sobelVert[2][1];
         tmp7 = (texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(-stepH, -stepV)).r *sobelVert[0][2]);
         tmp8 = (texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(0.0, -stepV)).r *sobelVert[1][2]);
         tmp9 = (texture2D(s_baseMap, coordVar.st + vec2(stepH, -stepV)).r *sobelVert[2][2]);
         pixelVSobel = tmp1 + tmp2 + tmp3 + tmp4 + tmp5 + tmp6 + tmp7 + tmp8 + tmp9 + 0.5;
         pixel = (sqrt(pixelVSobel*pixelVSobel +pixelHSobel*pixelHSobel));
         if (pixel <= 0.715)
         {
            pixel=0.0;
         }
         else
         {
            pixel=1.0;
         }
         // ###########IMPORTANCE MATRIX########### 
      float impmap = (pixel+diffmap)/2.0;
         // ########## display ######
          gl_FragColor = vec4(impmap,impmap,impmap,1.0);
```

I need to now somehow run a sobel filter on the image impmap.

Comment: We need some code, how do you currently write the filtered image? do you use load_store_images, do you work with an FBO, readpixels, ...?

Comment: sorry i could not put the code in the comment so i updated the question hope u can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a framebuffer object (FBO) your sobel filtering is written to a texture, instead of the on-screen framebuffer. You can then bind this texture instead of your original image and apply another filter pass on it.

So the order of operations would about as:

1. bind original image as texuring source
2. bind target texture as FBO color attachment
3. render original image via sobel shader to target FBO
4. unbind target texture as FBO color attachment and bind as texturing source
5. bind secondary target texture as FBO color attachment
6. goto 3, repeat as often as needed.